# Energy of Free-electron Gas - Landau Levels in 3D

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, quantum-hall-effect

I am looking into Landau Diamagnetism and am reading Dupre's paper. I am slightly confused at where he has got a term in his value of $E$ from.

He states that:
$$ 
E=(n+1/2)\hbar\omega+\hbar^2k_z^2/2m
$$
and I can easily get to the first part, but am confused where the second term $\hbar^2k_z^2...$ comes from as it always seems to disappear.

The Hamiltonian I am using is
$$
H=(-\hbar^2/2m)*d^2/dy^2+\hbar^2k_z^2/2m+m\omega_c/2(y-\hbar k_x/m\omega_c)
$$
however I may have the wrong indices (it could be $k_x$ or $k_z$ switched - I'm not certain)

Comment: It could be helpful to add a link to the *"Dupre's paper"*

Comment: What do you mean when you say that term "disappear(s)"? Can you show us at exactly which step in your derivative it disappears?

Answer (score 1):

You can think about it classically. If you have a charged particle moving in a straight line and you put a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ in the $z$-direction, its motion will change but not the velocity in the $z$-direction (because Lorentz force is zero in that direction $F\propto\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}$).

The same happens with the electrons in your Fermi gas (free electron model if you wish), the magnetic field is confining the motion in a plane perpendicular to $\mathbf{B}$ but not in the $z$-direction. So basically you have some quantized motion in the $xy$-plane but you have the equivalent to a 1D free particle in the $z$-direction. The energy of a free particle you can write it as you wish $E_z=\frac{p_z^2}{2m}=\frac{\hbar^2k_z^2}{2m}$ but $(E_z,p_z,k_z)$ are just free parameters that can go from $0$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I trust the energy in the z-direction is negative as no way for the electron to go in that direction. This implies that k_z is imaginary as the wave in the z-direction must be decaying.